# Elementarily equivalent forcing extension?

Tags: logic, set-theory, forcing

Is it possible to take a forcing extension which is elementarily equivalent to the ground model? Here I'm assuming the extension is proper, that is, it adds a new set.

It's clear it can't be an elementary extension (the forcing notion has a generic filter in the extension but not the bottom), which is why I ask about equivalence. Some hypotheses would prevent this (no forcing extension of a model of V=L is still a model of V=L), so this is really a question about consistency.

It's also clear by a pigeonhole principle argument that since there are many forcing extensions but few complete extensions of ZFC, some pair of them must have the same theory. But this doesn't mean they have the same theory as the ground model.

Any thoughts?

Comment: I am not sure I understand your pigeonhole principle argument. Are you talking about forcing extensions of $V$? Because then mentioning extensions of $\mathsf{ZFC}$ is out of place. Are you talking instead about forcing extensions of set models of $\mathsf{ZFC}$? Because then I do not understand how you conclude that there are "many" extensions (many forcing posets?). There could just be countable models, and countably many posets.

Comment: Fair enough, I may have been too quick. My thought was, there are continuum many possible theories of forcing extensions, but class many posets, so class many forcing extensions. Consequently some two of them must have the same theory. But this argument lives in some model of ZFC, I guess, so it's no longer true to say there are class many posets trivially. Also, different posets may yield equal (!) forcing extensions, which had not occurred to me.

Comment: Note that your argument that $V\not\prec V[G]$ is incomplete: we need that $V$ is definable in $V[G]$ (from parameters). This was proved by Laver and Woodin independently, but is far from trivial.

Comment: Why do we need that? It's simply true that there is a sentence (with parameters in V) which is true in V but false in V[G]

Comment: @RichardRast What is that sentence? Saying "is $V$-generic" uses $V$ as a "parameter" . . .

Comment: @NoahSchweber For some $\alpha$, $V_\alpha^V\ne V_\alpha^{V[G]}$. That's all.

Comment: @AndrésCaicedo Oh, of course, that's quite right.

Comment: No, just "there is a generic filter for P." The filter G is generic for P in V[G], too. We don't add new elements to P. Here we're using P as a parameter.

Comment: @RichardRast That's not correct - genericity is defined relative to models. Saying "$G$ is $P$-generic over $V$" means that $G$ meets every dense subset of $P$ which is in $V$; I don't know what "$G$ is $P$-generic" means. In particular, $G$ will **not** be generic for $P$ in $V[G]$, since (unless P is trivial) it won't meet the dense set "is incompatible with $G$," which certainly exists in $V[G]$! As Andres says, your statement is indeed true, but it's not that simple. (cont'd)

Comment: We can, however, express "$G$ is $P$-generic over $V$" without defining $V$, or referring to ranks: in $V$, there is some set $D$ which is the family of all dense subsets of $P$ (in $V$). Then the statement "$D$ is the family of all dense subsets of $P$" is true in $V$ but (unless $P$ is trivial) not in $V[G]$.

Comment: Ah! That's a serious error on my part. So sorry. I was somehow mixing dense sets with forcing conditions in my mind.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sure. Consider when $V=L[c]$ where $c$ is a Cohen real over $L$. If we force to add a second Cohen real $r$ over $V$, the result is again a Cohen extension of $L$.

And because the Cohen forcing is homogeneous, every two extensions are elementarily equivalent. So both $V$ and $V[r]$ are elementarily equivalent.

Comment: Note that $L$ isn't doing anything here: if $M$ is any model of $ZFC$, and $G, H$ are mutually Cohen generic over $M$, then $M[G]\equiv M[H]\equiv M[G][H]$.

Comment: Right. In fact it looks like these extensions are actually isomorphic, as opposed to just equivalent, which is interesting.

Comment: @RichardRast They're not isomorphic as long as your ground model is actually well-founded, since well-founded models of ZFC are rigid.

Comment: They do, however, have isomorphic *degrees of constructibility*.

Comment: Hmm, that seems to be an interesting question, actually. Assuming $\mathsf{ZFC}$ is consistent, are there models $M\subset M[c]$ where $c$ is Cohen over $M$ and such that $M$ and $M[c]$ are isomorphic? This sort of thing has probably been looked at before...

Comment: (Joel Hamkins provided me with some references showing that the result I asked about in the comment above indeed holds. The argument goes by appropriately generalizing some facts previously known in the context of nonstandard models of arithmetic. To get started, see Lemmas 5 and 6 [here](http://arxiv.org/abs/1104.4450).)